# Reference implementation of desktop SSO Client (in C/C++), Kerberos-based auth (server side is Java and MS AD)

Tags: single-sign-on, kerberos, autologin, spnego

we need to implement desktop SSO for a Rich Client in a managed Windows environment (some Vista machines, some Citrix clients with Win 2008 Citrix backend).

The rich client (written in C/C++) connects to a server using SOAP web services. The server is a Java application running on JBoss EAP. The user data is stored in a Microsoft ActiveDirectory. ADFS 2.0 is not available for us. The rich client does not make use of the Internet Explorer components.

We plan to employ PicketLink on the serverside. **However, the central question is: how do we inject SSO into the C/C++ client?** Which APIs do we use? My understanding is that we need to read the Kerberos tokens in the client, but I would like to avoid implementing all the Kerberos interactions by hand. Is there any abtraction layer in the Windows API? Any third-party libraries?

**Maybe there is an open-source reference implementation or product which shows how to implement Kerberos-based rich client SSO in managed Windows environment?**

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP as your SOAP transport you could simply use Microsoft's WinHTTP. It has SPNEGO support out of the box. Those tickets will be happily accepted by JGSS. If you really need to see how to use SSPI on the client-side check out the C source code of libneon or libserf. But all of the three libs will serve HTTP with SPNEGO out of the box.

Note: neon will need one small patch but this one is available on the mailing list.
Note 2: I presume that everything else works: domain, dns, accounts, spns and so forth.